# Dropping SQL foreign key on a live database

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, foreign-keys

Would I run into any issue if I tried dropping a foreign key constraint on a live SQL database? I want to make sure there's no reason to take the database offline before doing this.

Answer (score 1):

Dropping a foreign key on the live databases can be done online without impacting your users. You may run into data quality issues though, I guess the foreign key was in place for a reason.